# Testing - Enzyme mapped components with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

So I have a component (BoardCompleted) that maps over its prop and produces a series of smaller components (BoardCompletedItem). The problem is the child component is connected to Redux.

I'm having trouble testing the mapping part. I can't seem to get the mapped child to show up. Or maybe I'm not looking for it in the right way... Can someone look at what I am doing wrong here.

First, here is the parent component, which does the mapping:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import BoardCompletedItem from '../BoardCompletedItem/BoardCompletedItem';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';  

export class BoardCompleted extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const myBoard = this.props.boards.find(board => board.id === this.props.currentBoardId);  
        const items = myBoard.completed.map((item, key) => (
            <BoardCompletedItem  
                item={item} 
                key={key} 
            />
        )); 

        return (
            <section className="g-column">
                <div className="g-item-title">
                    <h3 className="g-title">Completed</h3>
                </div>
                { items }
            </section>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentBoardId: state.currentBoardId,
    boards: state.boards
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BoardCompleted);
```

Here is the child component:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group'; 
import { deleteCompleted } from '../../actions/mainActions'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 

export class BoardCompletedItem extends React.Component {

    handleDelete() {
        const value = this.props.item.value; 
        const board_id = this.props.currentBoardId; 
        const user_id = this.props.currentUser.id
        this.props.dispatch(deleteCompleted(value, board_id, user_id)); 
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
                <div > 
                    {this.props.item.value}
                    <div className="g-graphic-button" onClick={() => this.handleDelete()}>
                        <i className="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentBoardId: state.currentBoardId, 
    currentUser: state.currentUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BoardCompletedItem);
```

Here is my test. I am clearly doing something wrong here:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'; 
import  BoardCompleted  from '../components/BoardCompleted/BoardCompleted'; 
import BoardCompletedItem from '../components/BoardCompletedItem/BoardCompletedItem';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; 
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

const middlewares = []
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)

describe('BoardCompleted', () => {
    it('renders BoardCompletedItem without crashing', () => {
        const initialState = {
            boards: [{id: 1, completed: [{value: 'example'}]}],
            currentBoardId: 1 
        }
        const store = mockStore(initialState)
        const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><BoardCompleted /></Provider>); 
        expect(wrapper.contains(<BoardCompletedItem />)).toEqual(true); 
    }); 
});
```

The test runs, but I get:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      true
    Received:
      false
```

Any thoughts? I'm newish to testing connected components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the test is right it is false, `<BoardCompletedItem />` is being rendered without the key and item so it isn't rendering as you are expected.

Change it to `<BoardCompletedItem item={item} key={key} />` and map the item and key with the mock data